# Transform 'abcd' to {'a' 'b' 'c' 'd'} in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to transform a string to a categorical array in which the categories are the characters.

Comment: What MATLAB version are you using? Prior to R2016b, which came out last week, arrays with strings/characters were of type `char` anyway.

Comment: @Adriaan True. The question was poorly made as I noticed now what I tried was {'a','b','c'} which creates a categoric array. Will update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make a cell-array of strings (chars) then use the `cellstr()` function. This will turn each row of a char array into a separate string in a cell-array. Since your `string` variable is a single row, use the single-quote character to transpose it to a column and then use  `cellstr()`:

```
string ='abcd'
A = cellstr(string')   % The single quote after the string variable transposes it to a column
```

The output `A` will be columnar, so to get a row cell-array stick another single quote after the `A`, for example in use with `categorical()` as you mention:

```
B = categorical(A')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`num2cell`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html) for this purpose as follows:

```
string ='abcd';
num2cell(string)
```

**Output:-**

```
ans = 
    'a'    'b'    'c'    'd'
```

Answer (score 0):

strings in matlab are already really a vector of characters.

```
str = 'abcd';
length(str) %4
str(1) %a
str(2:3) %bc
```

Comment: The question was poorly made. I'm sorry. Please delete the answer and try to add another one.

Comment: As I commented ealier, yes, but this is only the case prior to R2016b. Since then, also the `string` datatype exists for strings/characters